# In find -perm, what's the difference between "+6000" and "/6000"?

Tags: command-line, permissions, find

I'm trying to find all the setuid/setgid binaries on my system. I've found two different ways to do this online.

What's the difference between

```
find / -perm +6000 -type f
```

and

```
find / -perm /6000 -type f
```

?

The latter is mentioned more often, and their results are the same. I want to make absolutely sure I don't miss any files. Are they the same?

I'm running this on an Ubuntu trusty box, but that could change in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The `find` manual page explains:

```
   -perm +mode
          Deprecated,  old way of searching for files with any of the per‐
          mission bits in mode set.  You should use -perm  /mode  instead.
          Trying to use the `+' syntax with symbolic modes will yield sur‐
          prising results. […]
```

So yes, they're the same thing, but you should use `-perm /mode`.

Answer (score 1):

The man page for GNU find says:

```
-perm /mode
  Any of the permission bits mode are set for the file.
  ...
```

and

```
-perm +mode
  Deprecated, old way of searching for files with any of the permission bits in  mode  set.
  You should use -perm /mode instead. Trying to use the ‘+’ syntax with symbolic modes will
  yield surprising results.
  ...
```

and gives some examples of what those surprising results would be.  So, they're equivalent, except that sometimes `+mode` can't be used and `/mode` can, so `+mode` should be avoided where `/mode` is supported.